# How to count nested relationship and append field by substracting number from result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have example query to get services from database:

```
$services = City::select('id', 'name')->has('services')
->with([
    'services:id,title,description',
    'services.reviews'
])
->get()->each(function($city) {
    return $city->services->each(function($service) {
        $service->setRelation('reviews', $service->reviews->take(3));
        return $service;
    });
});
```

And this return something json response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "London",
        "services": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Service title",
                "description": "Service description",
                "reviews": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "author": "John Doe",
                        "description": "Service review description"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

By default I get 3 reviews to each service in my case. How can I attach the number of remaining reviews to each service. To do this, first need count total number of reviews for the service and subtract 3 and if the result is greater than 0 then it will assign a value, otherwise it will assign the value 0.

Comment: have u tried laravel `withCount()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes, I tried but it's count all reviews and not attch to nested relationship service in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will work

small calculation i added may be it will work

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

`offset()` calculating and take 3

```php
 $services = City::select('id', 'name')->has('services')
            ->with([
                'services:id,title,description',
                'services.reviews'
            ])->get()->each(function ($city) {
                return $city->services->each(function ($service,$key) {
                     $offset = $key*3; // so get 3 multiple 
                    $service->setRelation('reviews', $service->reviews->offset($offset)->take(3));
                    return $service;
                });
            });
```